# Can't attach correct session tmux in linux

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I have implemented multiple sessions with tmux in ubuntu. I forgot give names for each. when I type **tmux ls** the result shows as follow

```
1: 1 windows (created Wed Feb 24 23:44:53 2016) [80x24]

2: 1 windows (created Thu Feb 25 22:37:13 2016) [80x24]

3: 1 windows (created Thu Feb 25 23:25:14 2016) [80x24]

4: 1 windows (created Fri Feb 26 03:18:03 2016) [80x24]
```

My question is how can I open one by one? Thank you

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. You may want to try over at [superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). But do read their help pages before posting to check whether your question is appropriate there.

Comment: @kaylum I faced to this problem when my site is deploying in ubuntu server. any way I found the solution by my self. If I put this on wrong place  thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we didn't give name for each they assign default names.

if you want to kill following session

```
1: 1 windows (created Wed Feb 24 23:44:53 2016) [80x24]
```

type following command

```
$ tmux kill-session -t 1:
```

if you want to attach above session

```
$ tmux a -t 1:
```